# API Gateway DynamoDB cross account integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to do a direct integration with API Gateway **to** DynamoDB. If both are in the same accounts, this works just fine, I've had no problems with the integration.

If they're in separate accounts, I can't figure out how to signal to API Gateway that the dynamo table is in a different account.

This setup Works:

- Account 111111111: API Gateway
- Account 111111111: Dynamo DB

This setup **does not**:

- Account 111111111: API Gateway
- Account 222222222: Dynamo DB

In the [docs](http://%20https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/integration/#uri) they specify what a uri integration should look like:

```
arn:aws:apigateway:{region}:{subdomain.service|service}:path|action/{service_api}
```

But I don't see where/if I can specify the account id of the existing table.

An arn of dynamo table usually looks something like this, `arn:aws:dynamodb:region:account-id:table/table-name`, so if I could supply an arn, this would should be plausible, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:dynamodb:action/Query
```

My questions are:

- Is it possible to do cross account integrations with API Gateway and Dynamo
- How can I specify the account id in an API integration?
- If I can't, is there a way to specify the account id in the query body somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've learned that cross account integration with API Gateway is not possible as API Gateway cannot assume a cross account role. The solution was to create a lambda, which can assume the cross account role.